# Reallocing a c array inside extern function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, realloc

Hi I'm trying to malloc a `char*` array in my `main()` then `realloc` in an extern function every time the parsing loop finds a file. All my code works except for the `malloc` and `realloc` of `char * files[]`.

When I run the following code I receive this error

```
*** Error in `./Assignment2': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007ffcefe78e50 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
--Lots of memory locations listed--
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char **files = malloc(sizeof(char*));

  /* parse the command line arguments */
  parseArguments( argc, argv,&files);
}
```

parse.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stddef.h";
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <argp.h>

char* printUsage();
extern int parseArguments(int argc, char *argv[], char *files[]) {
  int i = 1;
  int amtFiles = 0;
  /** Loops through each item turning on and off switches*/
  while (argc > 1) { /* i moves left to right 0 is file name so start at 1*/

      if (isFile(argv[i]) == 1) { /*if its a file */
        *files = realloc(files, amtFiles * sizeof *files);
        *files[amtFiles] = argv[i];
        /*printf("%s",*files[amtFiles]);*/
        amtFiles++;
      }

    }
    i++;/* increment argv[i] to next inputted char*/
    argc--; /* decrement the total amount of arguments to go through */

  }/*Loop ends */

}
```

I'm assuming its a pointer error but having a hard time figuring it out as I'm new to C and pointers are still a little confusing. If you could also include a link or explanation it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `*files = realloc(files, amtFiles * sizeof *files);` What a mess!

Comment: Look at what you are reallocing and what you are assigning the return to. `*files` and `files` are not the same thing. It may help to draw a diagram.

Comment: Format improved but a `{` is still missing somewhere - or an extra `}` is coded.  Missing return value

Comment: Wrong size in   `*files = realloc(files, amtFiles * sizeof *files);`  Unclear how to correct as coding goal is not apparent to me.

Comment: @chux may be missing one i just trimmed my code quickly to give an example, and my goal is to create the list in main but be able to realloc it as i need in parse.c. Its going to be a list of file names stored in main in the end but i never know how many files will be used

Comment: Code `extern int parseArguments(int argc, char *argv[], char *files[]) ;` before   `main()` to get a compiler warning with `parseArguments( argc, argv,&files);`.  Fully enable the compiler warnings.  Address the ones you can, post the ones you cannot.  It saves you and us time.

Comment: @John3136  I'm new to c ,how would you suggest I do it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score -1):

---

In your main files is a char ** (and you pass its address so the parameter is actually a char ***) but parseArguments only takes a char*[].

Add a prototype for In your main files is a char ** (and you pass its address so the parameter is actually a char ***) nut parseArguments only takes a char*[]. in main.c and the compiler would tell you about this. I suspect it is your main that is correct but I have not parsed through the code to make sure of that.